# I can't open a static file with NGiNX root function

Tags: nginx

I am trying to open a static file with root function. Here is my NGiNX config:

```
location = /test {
            root    /var/53c74dc1c284ff0d63b019fd736f2c7965939e0452104120130821064016.png;
    }
```

I get this error in my browser:

> **404 Not Found**

Also it does not seem to produce any errors in the NGiNX error logs.

I am using Ubuntu 12.

And I am using NGiNX version 1.2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to serve a single, specific file with the URI given for that `location`, use `alias` instead of `root`.

```
location = /test {
    default_type image/png;
    alias /var/53c74dc1c284ff0d63b019fd736f2c7965939e0452104120130821064016.png;
}
```

Loading `http://www.example.com/test` will then serve the named file.

Comment: It's forcing me to download the png image. Is there a way to view the image directly inside the browser? I tried types {} but it did not work.

Comment: That's because it has no extension so nginx sends it as an `application/octet-stream`. Add in `default_type image/png;` inside this `location` to fix that.

Comment: It does not work. It still forces a download.

Comment: It now works. It was the caching.

Answer (score 0):

The `root` command is for directories, not files.

Try this, and move the PNG under your normal web root:

```
    location / {
            try_files test /53c74dc1c284ff0d63b019fd736f2c7965939e0452104120130821064016.png;
    }
```